# Line Break After Dropdown in HTML

Tags: html, html-select

I am trying to add a submit button after a dropdown list in an HTML form. I am unable to add a line break between the dropdown list and submit button. Attached is a [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM13H.png) of the form. Below is the code I am using. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>   
    
    </head>

        <body>
    
        <form>
          
        <div>
          <input required type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"><br>
          <br><input required type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
          <br><input requiredtype="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
          <br><input required type="text" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number"><br>
          <br><input required type="text" name="handicap" placeholder="Handicap"><br>
          <br><select required name="shirtsize" size = 1>
            <option value="" selected>Shirt Size</option>
            <option value="S"> S </option>
            <option value="M"> M </option>
            <option value="L"> L </option>
            <option value="XL"> XL </option>
            <option value="XXL"> XXL </option>
            <option value="XXXL"> XXXL </option>
            <input type="submit" value=Register>
        </div>
                
        </form>

            
        </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the select and add a line break (`<br>`)

```html
<select required name="shirtsize" size = 1>
  <option value="" selected>Shirt Size</option>
  <option value="S"> S </option>
  <option value="M"> M </option>
  <option value="L"> L </option>
  <option value="XL"> XL </option>
  <option value="XXL"> XXL </option>
  <option value="XXXL"> XXXL </option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit" value=Register>
```

Answer (score 0):

@David is exactly right, I'd add a second line break though to keep the format similar to your picture.

```html
<select required name="shirtsize" size = 1>
  <option value="" selected>Shirt Size</option>
  <option value="S"> S </option>
  <option value="M"> M </option>
  <option value="L"> L </option>
  <option value="XL"> XL </option>
  <option value="XXL"> XXL </option>
  <option value="XXXL"> XXXL </option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value=Register>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you both for the help!